# What is a FeedbackVector in V8?

Tags: v8

[This article](https://v8project.blogspot.de/2018/04/improved-code-caching.html) mentions Feedback vectors:

> Ignition uses data-driven inline caches to fast-path operations in the current execution context. The context-dependent data is stored in feedback vectors and is separate from the generated code.

[This file](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/feedback-vector.h) seems to be an implementation of a FeedbackVector.

What are Feedback Vectors and what's their utility?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as that snippet says: FeedbackVectors are the data structure where data-driven inline caches store context-dependent data. They have this name because they're vectors (in the C++ sense, i.e. arrays) used for feedback (type feedback and other execution feedback, e.g. about called functions).

The article you read also contains a link to this video of a talk explaining that system in more detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7zRSm8jzvA